# Use youtube-dl on Windows 10 S

Tags: youtube-dl, windows-10s, uwp

Is there any method to run `youtube-dl` on Windows 10 S ? For example any UWP app allowing cmd sort of functionality.

Comment: Windows 10S is deliberately crippled to disallow all functionality, that is not explicitly approved by Microsoft. By using it, you agreed to that.

Comment: But, I don't think it would be impossible to use youtube-dl. All one need is internet access, command line interface and storage space.

Comment: But you don't have access to programs that run via the command line. The only applications that can run are Windows Store applications. That's the whole point of 10S. If you want the functionality back you need to buy either Home or Pro editions. Or find someone who wants to rewrite youtube-dl and put it on the Windows Store.

Comment: Neither access to the command line nor unfettered access to storage space are functionalities, that are explicitly approved by Microsoft. See above.

Comment: @EugenRieck Submit a detailed answer on this can be accomplished on Windows 10 S, because like Mokubai, I don’t believe it’s possible

Comment: @Ramhound - I said this was disallowed by Microsoft!